# Iterate over Dictionary.Key that is inside of an Array C#

Tags: c#, arrays, dictionary

Let's assume `myArray` is an array with strings ["first", "second", "third"], and `myDictionary` is `Dictionary<string, object>` with keys as a string ["first", "second", "third"].

So my question is, what would be best way for iterating over `myArray` and each iteration compare it's current value to `myDictionary`'s each element, and if they match do stuff?

At the moment I'm confused because of too many iterations. Here's my code snippet:

```
foreach (var value in myArray)
{
    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> entry in myDictionary)
    {
        if (entry.Key.Contains(value))
        {
            // Do stuff...
        }
    }
}
```

Obviously the problem is that there are too many iterations, any thoughts?

Comment: What about `myDictionary.ContainsKey` instead of the second loop?

Answer (score 1):

using Linq:

```
string[] myArray = new string[] { "first", "second", "third" };
Dictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
dict.Add("first", "aaa");

var arrayElementsThatExistAsDictKeys = myArray.Where(element => dict.ContainsKey(element)).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> entry in myDictionary.Where(x => myArray.Contains(x.Key)))
{
    // Do stuff...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (var value in myArray)
{
    if(myDictionary.Containskey(value)
    {
         var entry = myDictionary[value];
         //do some 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make use of [`TryGetValue`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb347013(v=vs.110).aspx) method of Dictionary class to reduce the iterations

```
foreach (var aVal in myArray)
{
    object outValue;
    if(myDictionary.TryGetValue(aVal, out outValue))
    {
        // Do your stuff here with outValue
    }
}
```